# How to fix language-level with deploy java heroku

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku

After push to git app  Deploy the application then issues a log

Error in writing that something is supported language versions above 1.6 but in the beginning you can see that the language version 1.7

```
> -----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.1.1... done
-----> executing /app/tmp/cache/.maven/bin/mvn -B -Duser.home=/tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository  -DskipTests=true clean install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO]                                                                         
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Building cashconverter 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Downloading:ada linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom (8 KB at 31.2 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.jar
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.jar (32 KB at 1587.3 KB/sec)
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cashconverter ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cashconverter ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ cashconverter ---
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.pom (867 B at 77.0 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-1.9.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-1.9.1.pom (4 KB at 220.6 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.20/plexus-components-1.1.20.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.20/plexus-components-1.1.20.pom (3 KB at 267.8 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.pom (692 B at 61.4 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.pom (688 B at 67.2 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.9.1/plexus-compilers-1.9.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.9.1/plexus-compilers-1.9.1.pom (2 KB at 121.4 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.jar
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar
       [INFO] Downloading: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.jar
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar (5 KB at 317.8 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.jar (21 KB at 1305.8 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloaded: linkhttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.jar (14 KB at 931.8 KB/sec)
       [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/target/classes
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/src/main/java/servlet/ConventerServlet.java:[64,20] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
       [ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
       /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/src/main/java/servlet/ConventerServlet.java:[80,20] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
       [INFO] 2 errors 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 3.135s
       [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 09 18:46:12 UTC 2015
       [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/514M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project cashconverter: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/src/main/java/servlet/ConventerServlet.java:[64,20] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
       [ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_0f74c7a1296de88f7a8d95975dd06c6b/src/main/java/servlet/ConventerServlet.java:[80,20] error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] linkhttp://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app
```

**pom.xml file**

>

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>cashconverter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>cashconverter</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.34</tomcat.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>



      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
          <version>20090211</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>cashconverter</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please tell me how fixed this problem

Comment: Does it build locally? Can you add your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to tell Maven to specifically use the version of Java you need. It is using its default, which [from the Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) (emphasis mine):

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the
>   **default target setting is 1.5**, independently of the JDK you run Maven
>   with. If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and
>   target as described in Setting the -source and -target of the Java
>   Compiler.

You should specifically tell the Maven compiler plugin to use the version of Java you want. Here is an example that is also [from the Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: where i must insert this settings?

Comment: Thank you very much the problem is solved

Perhaps you know how I can change the address of the page such as this on www.mysite / apps.html such www.mysite / apps

Comment: @Partizanin That would be better suited towards asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the maven-compiler-plugin was not necessary, only had

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

in pom.xml.
Deployed the app with `heroku:deploy` command, no problem (my code had Java 8 features).

And as soon as I tried to push to the app repository manually (for fun) using `git push`, the `-source 1.5` error appeared, and I could not even deploy with `heroku:deploy` anymore.

Had to use **mkobit's** solution. It seems that as long as you don't push manually while using Maven and Heroku, you can use `heroku:deploy`.

Also, be sure that all settings in your IDE for the project correspond to source 1.7 or whatever you need.